# Fetch a public post from Facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to fetch the comments of a post that I did to a Facebook page, but it's returning an empty JSON.

I tried this url: https://graph.facebook.com/514371788579576_526801224003299/comments

After that I tried with an extra access token parameter from my app but it didn't work either...

Any idea why it's return an empty JSON array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use FQL comment table to get the comments.

```
select text from comment where object_id = <POST_ID> and fromid = me()
```